# Related to css loading

Tags: css, reactjs

I am not able to load style sheet in my react app:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
 }
.App p {
  color: blue;
}
```

I am trying to print file on console then this is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Rajendra! It's not quite clear what you are asking. Could you try to elaborate some more, and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i am trying to import CSS file like:
"import style from "./App.css""

Comment: @RajendraSingh import css file as follows: 
import './MyCompStyle.css';

Comment: have you checked the network tab? Does it load the file? If so have you tried a hard refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting the project from scratch using React, you will probably need to learn how to use the bundling tools such as

- Webpack
- Rollup
- Parcel

They will give you the ability to use tools like css-loader which will allow you to import your css file into your react component in the header in this way:

```
import 'app.css'
```

Alternatively, you can just use react 'style' attribute directly on the component:

```
const style = {
  app: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  p: {
    color: 'blue'
  }
};
```

And you can apply the style in this way:

```
<App style={style.app}>
  <p style={style.p}>Hello world!</p>
</App>
```

For more information of using style, you can check the React official docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style